# How can I see if my Emacs was built with xft support?

Tags: emacs, archlinux

I've installed emacs using pacman on Arch linux. How can I see if it has xft support or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably more elegant ways to get this information, but the buffer created by `M-x report-emacs-bug` contains information about the build options.  Too lazy to go and check where it fetches this information.  Just kill the `*mail*` buffer once you have gleaned the information you need.

Answer (score 7):

This does it for me:

```
ldd `which emacs` | grep libXft
```

If it's built with libXft, you should get:

```
libXft.so.2 => /usr/lib/libXft.so.2 (0xb6df9000)
```